opening an image in /tmp with Pinta
I have Pinta 2.1.1 running in Flatpak (v1.14.5). When I run Pinta from the command line passing an image located in /tmp as an argument, it complains about the file not existing:
$ /var/lib/flatpak/exports/bin/com.github.PintaProject.Pinta  /tmp/img.jpg 

Pinta: GLib.GException: Error when getting information for file “/tmp/img.jpg”: No such file or directory

I am guessing this is due to /tmp being blacklisted by default, and Pinta not configured to enable access to it.
However, once the application is running, said image can be opened via 'Open file' (Ctrl+o) dialog.
Is this expected?
